# Most simple button doesn't work

Tags: python, html, flask, pythonanywhere

I have a really easy submit button in HTML, but it doesn't work.

**main_page.html**

```html
<form class="main_page" method="POST" action=".">
    <div class="form-row">
         <input type="submit" name="invoer" value="Invoeren"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**flask_app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])

def main():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("main_page.html")

    if request.form["invoer"] == "POST":
        return render_template("main_page.html")
```

When I click on the button, it shows me this:

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[image: https://i.gyazo.com/65bb8c9fa02d007a8ed8d3d465412e4f.png]

---

I already made a button like this before but then it worked, maybe I did something different. What should I do?

Comment: 1. So did you look at the logs; and 2. is that really your HTML? It's obviously broken.

Comment: 1. Yes I did already, but it gives me this https://pastebin.com/pZE0KY3E and I have no idea why and what it means. 2. The HTML is only a part of the full html file, I added the ''<'' which I missed when copying. Why the downvote....

Comment: Put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: It's all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is showing that `ValueError: View function did not return a response`, it means your POST didn't return any response to template when you click submit button in HTML. Chagne your code `flask_app.py` to:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])

def main():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("main_page.html")

    if request.method == "POST": # change code here
        return render_template("main_page.html")
```

This will make it works, however, it will return just the same template.

Comment: That's what I needed! Thanks :)